# How to click on Open/save/save as/cancel button on IE 11 using vba

Tags: vba

I would like to click on open when a file download dialog appear in IE 11. I found this code http://www.siddharthrout.com/2011/10/23/vbavb-netvb6click-opensavecancel-button-on-ie-download-window/

But this code does not work with IE11. I have also attached the IE11 download dialog box here too. Anyone has any idea, please, help.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use Alt+N to focus on the Notification Bar.
And then send {tab} key to navigate to the specific button.

With VBA, you may use **Autohotkey.dll or AutoItX3.dll** to send these hotkey combinations.